# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - How to work around dynamic text and countdown timer?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, wait

I am working on automating a sign up that contains a counter.

So the thing is, I want to sign up to something that occurs every 7 minutes.

Here is what the web code looks like:

```html
<class-countdown-timer _ngcontent-c19="" _nghost-c24="">
  <!---->
  <h2 _ngcontent-c24="" id="class-countdown-timer">Próxima clase en vivo en <span _ngcontent-c24="" class="countdown-timer">02:15</span>
    <i _ngcontent-c24="" aria-hidden="true" class="icon-clock"></i>
  </h2>
</class-countdown-timer>
```

My issue is that the "class-countdown-timer" text is dynamic and the "countdown-timer" its a countdown, from 07:00 to 00:00.

My cry for help is that I need to perform a certain action when the "class-countdown-timer" text is "Próxima clase en vivo en  " and the counter is in between "05:00" and "02:00"

I can't get to work a fluent wait that waits until first, countdown text shows the above and the timer is between those times, any idea?

thanks :D

Comment: Hi Jeff! i am a new user to Stack Overflow and new to the programing scene! thanks for your comment, i will do so for further questions!

Comment: The advice was intended not only for future questions but for this one also. It's important that *every* question follow the guidelines and standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
// Count-down timer for looping upto 8 minutes
        int countdown = 480;
        while(countdown-->0) {
            // Fetching the actual class-countdown-timer value
            String actualTimerText = driver.findElement(By.id("class-countdown-timer")).getText().trim();
            String expectedTimerText = "Próxima clase en vivo en ";

            // Fetching the actual countdown-timer value
            String countdownTimer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='countdown-timer']")).getText().trim();

            // Converting the time for better comparing
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            Date expectedFirstTime = format.parse("05:00"), expectedSecondTime = format.parse("02:00");
            Date actualCountdownTimer = format.parse(countdownTimer);

            // Checking the condition if the 'class-countdown-timer' text is 'Próxima clase en vivo ee' and counter is in between '05:00' and '02:00' or not? 
            if(actualTimerText.equals(expectedTimerText) && ((actualCountdownTimer.equals(expectedSecondTime) || actualCountdownTimer.after(expectedSecondTime)) && (actualCountdownTimer.equals(expectedFirstTime) || actualCountdownTimer.before(expectedFirstTime)))) {
                System.out.println("Condition Satisfied...");
                // Do something
                break;
            }
            // Waiting for one second before finding the element and checking the condition
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

The above approach is using the looping concept, iterate up to 8 minutes(480 seconds) until the required condition get satisfied.

Comment: Hi Ali! Wow! thanks for the fast response and help! i will bother you with some questions, to fully understand your feedback! :D

the first piece of code: initializes countdown as 480, but dont understand whats the while condition "countdown-->0" it is while countdown is greater than 0 do the below?

Because the countdown timer and the text varies, From "Proxima clase" to "Proxima registracion" and both has a 7 minutes countdown. what would occur when "actualTimerText.equals(expectedTimerText)" doesnt match?

Comment: From the second piece of  code:
The first part "class-countdown-timer" its always available with different texts. so does the "//Span...countdown-timer". i dont understand what does the first fluent wait do or why are they used for.

MANY MANY MANY MANY Thanks

Comment: In the first piece of code, up to 8 minutes(480 seconds) we are trying for the required condition to occur(the "class-countdown-timer" text is "Próxima clase en vivo en " and the counter is in between "05:00" and "02:00") and I'm decreasing the 'countdown' variable value until it gets negative because within 8 minutes if we don't find the answer then `countdown-->0` will break the while loop.

Comment: You catch the good point in second piece code, needs to modify a bit

Comment: when `actualTimerText.equals(expectedTimerText)` doesn't match then other condition will get executed `actualTimerText.greater(expectedTimerText)` => this is like checking `sometime >= 02:00` and 'sometime <= 05:00' individually. If the both conditions fail then loop will continue until it finds match up to 8 minutes(480) seconds

Comment: I think the second piece of code will not work if we modify also because like as you said there is not point of waiting for 'class-countdown-timer' and 'countdown-timer' because they(elements) already present and only the values are getting changed.

Comment: The first one worked like a charm, but when trying to compile and run i get an error in the ".parse" java.Text.pareseException :(

tried to modify the second piece of code but its gone now T_T

Comment: Can you tell at what line exactly the code is failing and for what input? Because we are extracting the timer text and parsing using SimpleDateFormate, the expected timer text should be in the 'hourhours:minutesminutes' format otherwise will get the parseException. The second piece of code I have removed from the answer because it makes no sense.